# How To Update URL Hash On Scroll (With Table Of Contents)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I found lots of answers on how to update a url hash when manually scrolled to, for example: `<a href="#one">Topic 1</a>`

However, what I really want is to update the hash when the user scrolls to, for example: `<h2><a name="one"></a>Topic 1</h2>`

I have a table of contents that allows the user to scroll to certain headings. But I also want to update the url hash automatically when the user scrolls to the H2 headings.

Here's a working example on of what I'm after on Healthline: https://www.healthline.com/health/baby/car-seat-expiration

**Example HTML**

```
Table Of Contents:
<a href="#one">Topic 1</a>
<a href="#two">Topic 2</a>

<h2><a name="one"></a>Topic 1</h2>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

<h2><a name="two"></a>Topic 2</h2>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

So basically, automatically update the url to include the hash when the user scrolls to each H2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seemed like fun so I tried it out.

You have anchors with name attributes throughout your page, likely inside of a header tag; let's say an H1, but any would do.

Just takes a small bit of script to find all instances of this when you're scrolling and by using the history API and a bit of string magic you can overwrite the current location without causing the page to jump.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const headings = document.querySelectorAll('h1 a[name]');
  
  document.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
    headings.forEach(ha => {
      const rect = ha.getBoundingClientRect();
      if(rect.top > 0 && rect.top < 150) {
        const location = window.location.toString().split('#')[0];
        history.replaceState(null, null, location + '#' + ha.name);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: There may be a better way, but it's a little late at night for me :)

Comment: This works perfectly! Best of all, no need to change our current pages. Is there a way to remove any hash if the user scrolls to the top of the page again?

Comment: I'm sure there is. Perhaps add a 0px by 0px div to the top of the page and add it to the query selector, then `history.replaceState(null, null, location + (ha.tagName === 'a' ? '#' + ha.name : ''))` (Untested)

Comment: Small addition (because browsers don't like too many history changes): 

```javascript
const oldHash = window.location.hash;
if ('#' + ha.name != oldHash) {
  history.replaceState(null, null, location + hash);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [History Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) and modify hash when user scroll document.

```
$(function() {
    $(document).scroll(function(){
      var that = this;
      $('section').each(function () {
        if ($(that).scrollTop() >= $(this).offset().top) {
        history.replaceState("data", "title", location.origin + location.pathname + '#' +  $(this).attr('id'));
        }
      });
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<section style="height: 900px" id="fisrt">
     <a href="#first">First</a>
</section>
<section style="height: 900px" id="example">
     <a href="#example">Example</a>
</section>
<section style="height: 900px" id="about">
      <a href="#about">About</a>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to this for my site and used section tags with name attribute in Vue 3.

```
methods: {
...mapMutations({
  setLoc: "updateCurrentLocation",
}),
handleScroll(evt) {
  const headings = document.querySelectorAll("section[name]");

  headings.forEach((ha) => {
    const rect = ha.getBoundingClientRect();

    if (rect.top >= 0 && rect.top < 50) {
      const hashed = "#" + ha.getAttribute("name");
      if (this.hash !== hashed) {
        this.hash = "#" + ha.getAttribute("name");
        this.setLoc("#" + ha.getAttribute("name"));
      }
    }
  });
},
```

},

Answer (score -1):

```html
Table Of Contents:
<a onmouseover="urlhash('#one')" href="#one">Topic 1</a>
<a onmouseover="urlhash('#two')" href="#two">Topic 2</a>

<h2><a name="one"></a>Topic 1</h2>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

<h2><a name="two"></a>Topic 2</h2>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

```
function urlhash (link) {
    window.location.hash  = link;
}
```

Comment: he want to change url hash on scroll not onmouseover.

Comment: Tested it out and the onmouseover causes it to scroll to the h2 when hovered, not a great UX for a table of contents. Also, I'm not getting the intended purpose where the url is updated with the hash after scrolling down without clicking on the table of contents links.

Comment: there's little amount of text first thing in my mind was mouseover.